# Google Play Store Error DF-BPA-10

Tags: android, google-play

I found nothing on stackoverflow for a Google Play Store error "DF-BPA-10", but I was able to resolve the issue and am posting this question and answer for anyone who runs into the same issue.

This issue occurred on my Samsung Galaxy SIII running Jelly Bean (4.1.1), but other devices may be affected.

Upon accepting terms and conditions for applications, an error notification appears stating "Error processing purchase: [DF-BPA-10]". Neither restarting the device nor force stopping the Play Store resolves the error.

Comment: You should post this Q & A on android.stackexchange. Stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to resolve the error, perform the following:

1. Open up the "Settings" app on your android device, then navigate to "Application manager".
2. Find "Google Play Store" on the list (should be alphabetical) and tap it.
3. Tap the "Force stop" button and confirm to close the application.
4. Tap the "Uninstall updates" button and confirm. This will take the Play Store back to the factory version.
5. Open up the Play Store and accept terms & conditions.

You should now be able to install applications without the DF-BPA-10 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue because of violating terms of service of google while using it's service, so Google wanted me to verify account before it would let me make purchases again.

So verifying account could work for same account in this case.