# Google Play billing: Error retrieving information from server. [DF-PPA-10]

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I have created a test app with In-App billing. Uploaded it to google play and sent it to beta testers. When they try to make purchase then they receive `Error retrieving information from server. [DF-PPA-10]` error.

[image]

We tried several accounts that are able to make purchases in Google Play. I did a test purchase with one of these accounts from another app and it works. But we always receive DF-PPA-10 error trying to purchase In-App in our beta tested app from different accounts/phones.

If we use account with expired card or without card then Google Play asks to enter card or PayPal. Once good card is added then we get `DF-PPA-10` error.

Comment: Your payment method might need to be checked or updated. you can try to change your payment method or use alternative forms of payment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/dkowob-NlG0 If the error still pop up, you can try to check your code with this repo: https://github.com/ianhanniballake/LocalStorage/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/ianhanniballake/localstorage/DonateActivity.java

Comment: I saw that link before asking that question. It is in top of google results. That is why I wrote that I can make purchases in Google Play with that account. I can't make purchase inside of my beta app.

Comment: Have you check this repo:https://github.com/ianhanniballake/LocalStorage/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/ianhanniballake/localstorage/DonateActivity.java

Comment: Yes. But it does not make sense at all. My app is modification of TrivialDrive that comes with Android SDK. and it should work. I already implemented google billing in past for other apps. I receive error message `DF-PPA-10` and I have no idea what is wrong and it is a problem.

Comment: Have you update the play service? what version are you using?

Comment: I have updated today and it has not changed anything.

Comment: @Max did you solve this issue? I have same problem, and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue recently. I could make successful purchases with the same card and account but suddenly it started giving me this error.

I am not sure why this should have happened but uninstalling  updates for Google Play Store from Settings > Application Manager resolved that error.

See
[Google Play Store Error DF-BPA-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767581/google-play-store-error-df-bpa-10) for more details.